# How to add new face_encodings in a existing face_encoding file in face_recognition module?

Tags: python-3.x, face-recognition

I want to save the face_encodings in a existing face_encoding file with face_recognition module, but I can't do it! Here's the code but without saving the face_encodings with the file's existing face_encoding:

```
def addorThat():
    def sel():
        root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file",
                                                   filetypes=(("Photo Files", "*.jpg"), ("all files", "*.*")))
        Label(lower_frame, text='File Location : ' + str(root.filename), font=40).pack()
        with open('text_required.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write((root.filename))
        return root.filename

    def train():
        print(entry.get())
        if str(entry.get()) != None:
            with open('text_required.txt', 'r') as f:
                u = f.read()
                print(u)
            boxes = face_recognition.load_image_file(str(u))
            all_encodings[entry.get()] = face_recognition.face_encodings(boxes)[0]
            messagebox.showinfo('Doing', 'Training has started!')

            with open('dataset_face.dat', 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump(all_encodings, f)
            messagebox.showinfo('Done', 'Training Completed')
        else:
            messagebox.showerror('No Name', 'Please enter the person name to train!')

    inputvar = StringVar()
    root = tk.Toplevel()

    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
    canvas.pack()

    background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file='landscape.png')
    background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_image)
    background_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

    frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff', bd=5)
    frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor='n')
    inputvar.set("Person Name")
    entry = tk.Entry(frame, font=40, textvariable=inputvar)
    entry.place(relwidth=0.65, relheight=1)
    button = tk.Button(frame, text="Take Picture", font=40, command=None)
    button.place(relx=0.7, relheight=1, relwidth=0.3)

    lower_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff', bd=9)
    lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')

    label = tk.Label(lower_frame)
    label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    but = tk.Button(lower_frame, text="Select Photo", font=40, command=sel)

    but.pack()
    # Label(lower_frame,text='File Location : '+str(sel),font =40).pack()
    butt = Button(lower_frame, text='Train', font=40, command=train)
    butt.pack()
    scroll = Scrollbar(lower_frame, orient=VERTICAL)
    scroll.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(lower_frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    root.mainloop()
```

If you need more information please inform me!